# How to find jar cointainign a given class

Tags: java, classpath, method-missing

I got an error for missing class "org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl". It is a new project setup, whitout employ maven or other tool to manage dependencies. 
I think to forgot to include some jar, how to find what jar own XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl?

Comment: This strongly depend on what kind of project you are working on.  maven is vastly different from non-maven projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because same class implementation could be packaged differently, you could find it on more jar. You have also to ensure that each class was included only once time, to prevent "no class found error".

A good service to locate parent jar for a given class:

http://www.findjar.com/

it helped me lot of times.

Comment: another option is help4j.com it provides source as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using eclipse:

Ctrl + Shift + T

Helping me to find quickly which class belongs to which jar.
However, these jars have to be in workspace.

Otherwise use @zeppaman seggestion: http://www.findjar.com/

Answer (score 3):

it was included in xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar, you can try http://www.findmaven.net , it can help you find the jar and the dependency tree of the jar

Answer (score 2):

another good place to find it would be http://www.findmaven.net